# HTML Windowbuilder for eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse-plugin, html-editor

Is the any html visual editor plugin for eclipse ?
Something like WindowBuilder Pro for HTML ?
I didn't find such an plugin and i am kind of confused i mean if you can create such an plugin/application for Swing it is not that hard to do the same thing for html.
And it would be very useful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A visual HTML editor ships with the [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) Eclipse plugins.

Comment: Thank you his !
I will try it and post my opinion here. But i would appreciate it if you guys can post more suggestions if there are any alternatives.
I will try them all and post my opinion on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Web Page Editor in WTP.It generates HTML code after dragging & dropping components.